# How to turn HTML link into ASP.NET MVC action link with attributes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I try to convert this HTML link

Projects

into MVC code, but I don't know how to add the `href` and the `aria-expanded` attributes

```
@Html.ActionLink("Project", "ProjectDetails", "Project", new { @class = "has-arrow" })
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: and what is the problem? Do you really need href?  You should test at first before asking the question.

Comment: yes i do its javascript action i needed

Comment: Void action? are you sure? if you need another action then leave as it is . In any case it will be converted to what you have already.

Comment: yes its been needed to fire action on this link

Comment: What are  you trying to do is called an html helper and it just converts to what you have already.

Comment: ok forget about the href how about the aria-expanded="false" attribute

Comment: Nobody does it, but if you are so determined try @aria-expanded="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following to your `ActionLink`:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Projects", "ProjectDetails", "Project", new {href="javascript:void(0)", @class = "has-arrow", @aria-expanded="false"})
```

This will convert to your `a` tag in the question

Answer (score 1):

its works like that

```
                @Html.ActionLink("Projects", "ProjectDetails", "Project", new { href = "javascript:void(0)", @class = "has-arrow", @ariaexpanded = "false" })
```